# Something like thread in php

Tags: php, sockets, curl

I'm trying to program yahoo messenger robot,now my robot can get messages and answer to them.
Yahoo only can send 100 pm at each time I get notification.

now I wanna answer the each pm. I use `while(true){ }` to it and answer first pm,then second ,then 3rd and ... .
It's so slow ,because I can make only one connection to yahoo by this(I use curlib).
how can I send some messages at same time?I think I need something like thread but in php.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use pcntl_fork(). http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pcntl-fork.php

You need pcntl extension and it only works on Unix

If you use curl function you might take a look at curl_multi_init(). http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-multi-init.php

Answer (score 0):

I've wrote a simple function below, which **launches URL, and doesn't wait for a result**, so like this you can launch many URLs on your own site, it will make your loop fast, and also no need to install any extensions to your server.

```
function call_url_async($url, $params, $type='POST', $timeout_in_seconds = 1)
{
    //call the URL and don't wait for the result - useful to do time-consuming tasks in background
    foreach ($params as $key => &$val) 
    {
        if (is_array($val)) 
            $val = implode(',', $val);
        $post_params[] = $key.'='.urlencode($val);
    }
    $post_string = implode('&', $post_params);

    $parts=parse_url($url);

    $fp = fsockopen($parts['host'], isset($parts['port'])?$parts['port']:80, $errno, $errstr, $timeout_in_seconds);
    //if ($fp == FALSE)
    //  echo "Couldn't open a socket to ".$url." (".$errstr.")<br><br>";

    // Data goes in the path for a GET request
    if ('GET' == $type) 
        $parts['path'] .= '?'.$post_string;

    $out = "$type ".$parts['path']." HTTP/1.1\r\n";
    $out.= "Host: ".$parts['host']."\r\n";
    $out.= "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n";
    $out.= "Content-Length: ".strlen($post_string)."\r\n";
    $out.= "Connection: Close\r\n\r\n";
    // Data goes in the request body for a POST request
    if ('POST' == $type && isset($post_string)) 
        $out.= $post_string;

    fwrite($fp, $out);
    fclose($fp);
}
```